# Can't access some array elements though allocated

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm programming on an STM32F407VG and allocate an array with 513 uint8_t's.

For some very strange reason `calloc` does not work with so many elements. Therefore I use `malloc` and initialize manually. However, the program fails when I initialize elements 400+.

I will add the code that does not work later.

Note that when I allocate say 1013 elements, I can initialize all 513 however i probably can't initialize some other elements.

I use coocox ide with the default libraries and a gcc arm compiler.

Why can't I access these elements? I do not have any debug info at runtime but the program stops execution which i can confirm by LEDs that don't light up, though they do when I initialize only elements 0-400.

Comment: What is your motivation for allocating this array dynamically, when you know what (constant) size you want it to be??? In any case, check your project linker-settings (possibly in a linker-command file or something similar), in order to make sure the amount of memory dedicated for each segment in your program (e.g., stack, data-section, code-section, heap, etc).

Comment: Right static allocation should work. Why havent i thought about this. I will ty this later and test if it works